# How are +variable+ and ${variable} different in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm start coding.

While I was watching a lecture, I saw code like this.

```
var coworkers = ['go', 'hello', 'hi', 'doit'];
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var i = 0;
        while(i < coworkers.length){
          document.write('<li>'+coworkers[i]+'</li>');
          i = i + 1;
        }
```

But But when I searched, Said to use ${variable} in JavaScript. and It didn't work.

How are +variable+ and ${variable} different in javascript? Thanks :)

Comment: @ProsyArceno Template literal syntax has nothing to do with jQuery

Answer (score -1):

Those placeholders, like ${variable}, can only be used in template literals, which are always enclosed in backticks(the key right below you escape key).

If it still doesn’t work, maybe you’re using an older browser?

Comment: Oh my god! I don't use backticks!! I solved problem. Thank you!!